# Host a server with NGINX using VPN behind a NAT

Tags: vpn, webserver, nginx, nat

I was hosting a server using NGINX on a Raspberry Pi using a T-Mobile mobile router. All was working fine, till I noticed today that T-Mobile started to put me behind a NAT sometimes.

[I heard](https://superuser.com/questions/277218/ssh-access-to-office-host-behind-nat-router) you can still access the server if you set up a VPN network or SSH-tunneling, but I have no idea on how to do it.

I searched on the internet but didn't find any tutorials on how to do it using a mobile network, so I thought to ask here. Sorry if this question has been answered before.

Comment: You need to ask a specific question and show what you have tried. Where did you hear this about the VPN, maybe that same source has a tutorial? Also, you should look through the questions that have already been asked, especially if you think that your question may have been asked already.

Comment: I edited the question. I looked through alot of questions but I think none apply to my case

Comment: "So I heard...." - something got lost in translation. You need something with an IP address exposed on the internet which will permit incoming connections (not a VPN) and your life will be a lot simpler if that thing has a static public IP address (not a VPN). Given your level of understanding, I am concerned about your ability to secure and maintain a host with an exposed web service on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to troubles of on premises servers.

This asymmetry is direct cause of proliferation and also unfair advantage in favor of cloud services.

Problem you are observing is caused by the fact that many ISPs simply don't sell you what I call "real internet access" anymore.

Especially with mobile operators, what you really get is some kind of crippled solution that is just glorified one-way data pipe for consuming content, that works for "plebs" (or so called "normies"), but is not really geared for publishing your own services on the internet.

Now the thing is with enough of duct tape and layers of abstraction you can overegineer around any problem, but in my experience it's always much better to solve the problem for real.

So now I have several routes of action for you:

1. Solve problem for real: get an "real internet access"
2. Rethink the problem: what are you trying to solve?
3. If two above fail, solve by "ductapizing" to death

Here are details of the solutions:

**1. Solve problem for real: get an "real internet access"**

I used to ductapize for my clients, but now that my time is more and more expensive I always push client toward real solution. Years into the future this always proved to work thousand times better.

Real solution in this case is to get an "real internet access" which has following poperties:

1. you get a real external ip (not behind NAT) (dynamic-ip is okay, but static is preferred)
2. you must have capability to open/redirect crucial ports

Talk to your T-Mobile representative, if they can offer you service with these attributes. Usually magical words that trigger the sales homunculi are "static ip" or your "own voip server", this will cause the shop to get you somebody competent, or deny you outright.

If shop denies you outright, it is often because they are actually styled as "home/family customer" shop. Many of these shops are only franchises (they just sell prepackaged T-Mobile connections and have T-Mobile branding but they don't really deal with operation of the connection, which is actual T-Mobile business).

If you get denied, while it seems like it is a dead end, it is not yet: you can get further, if you change your thinking 180 degrees and rebrand yourself as business. Yes I know.

For example, in my personal case, I founded a company for myself and operate all my connections, even home and mobile ones through that company. As company I am eligible to contact T-Mobile, Orange, O2 (or what have you) Business Services. They often have completely different sales playbooks and can offer you completely different connection types for the same area and access points. Business Services unit is more often then not an actual daughter company of the ISP, rather than some "normie stuff" franchise.

In my experience, even support calls, as business customer, are shorter and ISPs AVRs diverts you to higher level technicians sooner (not to just some human parrots and human recorders repeating some phrases in loop (have you restarted your router?), but real technical people actually solving your problem).

For the client, I sometimes do call all mobile operators in the area and get business programs from each of them and call them all again and pitch their offerings against thmeselves (you would be surprised how many times, especially Orange can come up with pleasant deal - they are very business oriented).

Also don't neglect small local (city/county/town level) operators, they often can have very, very interesting deals using completely different technology (often WIFI). As they are smaller companies, the deal is often much more tweakable towards you.

If you get static IP you are golden. With static IP you can now easily directly assign world visible DNS name to your server (IE you can connect from almost anywhere).

If you get only dynip - you must now ducttape publishing IP update to internet somehow: either you write your own sloution with help of yet antoher webserver/webhosting or use dynip service like no-ip.org (there are many like it).

In my exprience (and depending on quality of the link) no-ip usually breaks badly once a year due to reasons. It is often more flaky than static IP.

The business level connection price is often in range 1.2-1.5, sometimes even 2.0+ times higher than comparable "normie" connection price, but almost always was I or my client very happy that we stuck to it.

My way of deling with it described is rather tedious and more expensive, but you pay for convenience, feasbility and in the end better service here.

I also want to remind you, that Carrier Grade NAT address pools were added to IANA reserved ip addresses pools some years ago, and these are quite big address pools which means more and more regular customers (aka normies) will be put into these NAT pools. It is quickly becoming mobile connection reality even where it wasn't some years ago (residential mobile connections). As amount of dynip and static ip addresses is rather limited, sooner you get one for your connection, the better off you will be in the future.

IPv6 was supposed to solve this, but this does not seem to be the case here, especially in mobile realm.

Requisites:

- Pi
- "real internet connection"
- nothing (raw ip) or domain with DNS edit ability for static ip, or no-ip/webserver for dynamic ip tracking, with static ip this third step is completely optional

**2. Rethink the problem: what are you trying to solve?**

But maybe your whole design and architecture is wrong. What are you trying to solve? Why are you running nginx on the Pi?

If you just want to publish your Pi data on the net you should do it the way all surveillance adware in the mobile space does it: you should buy some server/webserver already on the net and push data from Pi to it. Ie you should reverse dataflow direction.

This way you don't need to worry about NAT piercing. Your Pi will connect to myserver.com (which is already readily accesible) and send data there. You can then observe Pi connections from myserver.com. Run computations batches and everything on the server and present digests through nginx running on myserver.com.

Woudln't this be better solution for yourself?

For that you must buy yet another service (unless you already have it): internet accessible server or webserver.

Requisites:

- Pi
- server/webserver/container/VPS on the net, preferably with DNS name

**3. If two above fail, solve by "ductapizing" to death**

If you cannot get good connection deal nor you are able to solve your problem by streaming data from Pi to the server, for example you need to be able to "remotely" access and "enter" the Pi system from the net, then yes, VPN is your only solution.

This is basically more complex variant of solution 2.) with a difference that instead of sending data from Pi to internet accessible server, you are actually instructing Pi to connect to internet accessible server through VPN tunnel.

Ie you must buy yet another service: internet accessible server.

This cannot be special case webhosting server, but real full fledged server (or at least VPS/container like lxc).

After you obtain the server you need to deploy VPN solution to both the Pi and the server:

- **SSH** can bridge Pi even with a cloud container (containers cannot load kernel modules)

  - you will have issues with SSH connection liveness monitoring, see autossh(1) for possible solution (sometimes detection breaks)
  - SSH "VPN" runs in userspace and is not very efficient, ie it is very low bandwith, but you can browse web trough it for example.
  - what it lacks in speed and liveness reliability, it gains in incredible flexibility - there are whole books written only about SSH tunneling
- **OpenVPN** can bridge Pi even with a cloud container (containers cannot load kernel modules)

  - OpenVPN can be slightly faster than SSH, it is still slow and rather inneficient as it still runs in userland
- **IPSEC** is very mature VPN technology, but it comes from corporate and military environment, thus it can get very quickly very complex to set up and maintaim (byzantine baroque configs, many moving partys, equipment and OS compatability issues), requires real server (at least virtualized VPS)

  - this is a technology that often connects company branch networks into one global company network spanning through whole internet (connects Tokio branch with New York branch and with Lodon branch and these together with datacenters in Amsterdam and Taiwan)
  - this will require real server (cannot be container/lxc, but can be virtual machine) as IPSEC kernel module must loaded into kernel

    - but kernel module is only half of the solution
  - this also requite IPSEC coordination software, on Linux often strongswan(1) is used - this thing coordinates the kernel and actually builds and binds the VPN connections together
  - as, after connection is setup, all the cryptocommunications happens directly in kernel - this is very performant solution, very fast data rates are possible
  - after gaining enough crypto knowledge and IPSEC expreniece, you might succeed in connecting cisco switches or windows boxes directly into the IPSEC VPN network, thus IPSEC network can be very heterogenous.
- **WireGuard** relative newcomer already breaking several records, requires real server (at least virtualized VPS)

  - very, very, very easy to setup - intentionally as simple as SSH (aims to replace SSH for VPNing) - if you ever dealt with complex IPSEC, difference between them is night and day
  - it loads into kernel as kernel module thus requires real VPS
  - uses very modern low power consumption high performance crypto
  - but thank to all that is also very, very fast (I am often getting 20 MBytes/s on 1GBit residential optics)
  - standard equipment of Linux and OpenBSD kernels some time
  - because it is so barebones is missing lot of autmation and tooling, ip routing is delegated to host os (ie linux), so you need to know well how to setup routing and packet forwarding

Requisites:

- Pi
- server/container/VPS on the net, preferably with DNS name
- VPN solution

---

To conclude from my experience: solution 1.) is often best and most optimal solution. Solution 1.) often can grow into very robust solution 3.) as your project expands (VPNs are great and simple over static IPs). Solution 2. is cheapest and easiest to implement if you able and willing to reverse your dataflows. Solution 3.) is most flaky and managerially expensive when combined with many clients (many call-in teleworkers with notebooks and "travelling" Pi systems)

Answer (score 0):

I like NAT. It sort off keeps the internet outside our private internet while still letting you access all the (public) internet. So security wise a nice thing, so to speak. In your case though, a nightmare. That's why NAT doesn't exist in IPv6. So first suggestion, can you get it to work with IPv6? Second suggestion, call T-Mobile and complain. Tell them you need to get a public IP address assigned, so you can access your Raspberry or anything else you like, e.g. video surveillance. You may need to complain a lot until you get to someone who understands what you are talking about.

Third suggestion, would a VPS in the internet be sufficient for your needs? VPS are cheap, powerful and can be used for a lot of things.

If all fails and you really need to have your Raspberry accessible from the internet, get a VPS, install the flavor of Linux that you like on it and setup a VPN from your Raspberry to the VPS. So the Raspberry is the client and the VPS the server.

Since you don't have a permanent IP address, you will need to configure the VPN to autodetect changes in IP configuration. For ssh you would need some custom scripts, since that feature is not included in ssh. "[Mosh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mosh_%28software%29)"  may be a better alternative to ssh.

Personally I would look at [StrongSwan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/StrongSwan) with [ikev2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Key_Exchange) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Key_Exchange for a vpn that can handle changing IP on the client side. Google for Roadwarrior configuration with strongswan.

I hope that helps to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

If you have another server somewhere you can run SSH tunnel to connect to it, or configure OpenVPN client on your RPi device to connect to it.

SSH tunnel can help you but it will be hard to maintain if connection lost due internet fails or something else.
OpenVPN looks more stable in my book.